# Strange behaviour in php hash_hmac

Tags: php, sha256, hmac

I am creating a simple api in php.

```
$signature_string = "MARCIGETapi/v1/test/636779232000000000FIXXISOFTRGllcyBpc3QgZWluIFRlc3Q="
$new_sig = hash_hmac("sha256",  $signature_string, $api_key, false);
echo $new_sig;
```

> 24f305d19cad2e848b3407f64bc21ada0ff1978a2487a23f26aa35f3a1c8204a

**Now explain me this**:

```
$new_sig = hash_hmac("sha256", "MARCIGETapi/v1/test/636779232000000000FIXXISOFTRGllcyBpc3QgZWluIFRlc3Q=" , $api_key, false);
echo $new_sig;
```

> c1d2347e60a648838fd8a98a41174fc9a4b18371e18261931f3337951b8a6cdf

The second one is the expected one I was able to generate on the c# client.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE of this problem. It shouldn't create a different hash just because the value is saved in a variable first. Maybe the `$signature_string` variable or the `$api_key` variable is changing.

Comment: i am pretty sure this can me reproduced using any string as api_key. I am 100% sure the data is the same (api_key is used both times). the 2 snippets are right after each other and api_key is never altered.

Comment: It can not be reproduced with just these code blocks. They will return the same hash, regardless if the message is written directly in the `hash_hmac()` call or via a variable. Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: WFM: https://3v4l.org/okmLH

Comment: I'm also having the same issue :( any solution you found? It's very strange issue I'm having

Comment: @JayMaharjan i cannot reproduce it anymore nor do i have the old project sadly. what php version are you using? Cau u provide some more info of your code?

Comment: The issue was appearing in my WordPress project. The issue was when I did var_dump for the variable it's showing different string count than the actual string count due to which the issue was appearing and I'm able to solve the issue using the WordPress function html_entity_decode() applying to that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve had the same problems in one of my projects.
Just try:

```
$new_sig = hash_hmac("sha256", trim($signatur_string," "), $api_key);
```

Comment: Then this is a completely different problem with your input.